# Why is it not possible to access state in another component using useHook in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to access the state from one component to another. To do so i want to wrap contextprovider only to the component where state changes on clicking a button and return state from a usehook so that another component can access the state.

below is how the componnet looks without context applied,

```
function Parent () {
    return (
        <UploadButton/>
    );
}

function UploadButton () { //this is where state is set
    const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState(false); 
  
    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsDialogOpen(!isDialogOpen);
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}/>
            {isDialogOpen && <Upload/>}
       </>
   );
```

}

function UserButton() { //this is where state is accessed
return (
 //this icon should be displayed only if !isDialogOpen
);
}

With context looks like below, I have DialogContext within same file where UploadButton is.

```
function Parent() {
    return (
        <DialogContextProvider>
            <UploadButton/>
        </DialogContextProvider>
     );
 }

interface DialogCtxState {
    isDialogOpen: boolean;
    setIsDialogOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
 }

 const initialDialogState: DialogCtxState = {
     isDialogOpen: false,
     setIsDialogOpen: () => {},
 };

 const DialogContext = React.createContext<DialogCtxState>(
     initialDialogState  
 );

 export const DialogContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
     const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false); 

     return (
         <DialogContext.Provider
             value={{
                 isDialogOpen,
                 setIsDialogOpen,
             }}
         >
             {children}
         </DialogContext.Provider>
    );
}
export function useDialogOpen() { //this is defined in uploadbutton component file
    const {isDialogOpen} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
    return isDialogOpen;//this is false althought upload button is clicked.
}

function UploadButton () {
    const {isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen} = React.useContext(DialogContext);
 

    const handleClick = () => {
        setIsDialogOpen(isDialogOpen => !isDialogOpen);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}/>
            {isDialogOpen && <Upload/>} 
        </>
    );
}
```

I access the state isDialogOpen in userbutton component like below,

```
function UserButton () {
    const isDialogOpen = useDialogOpen();
    return (
        {!isDialogOpen && <Icon/>} //here isDialogOpen is false although when button in upload button 
        //is clicked and hence makes Icon render.
    );
}
```

I am not sure how to fix this. could someone help  me with this. thanks.
);

Comment: `UserButton` is wrapped in the same `DialogContextProvider` as `UploadButton`?

Comment: No i dint wrap it. i thought i need not wrap it if use useHook like useDialogOpen method so that would provide the state.

Answer (score 0):

If that `isDialogOpen` state is needed only for the child's parent component, Why should you use `context` ?

( [Context is designed to share data that can be considered “global” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)  )

You can simply pass `isDialogOpen` state to parent using a parent's callback function as prop ref to be called inside the child.

I think this is the solution. [React Hooks - How to pass props from child to parent component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413565/react-hooks-how-to-pass-props-from-child-to-parent-component/62414218#62414218)

Comment: it is needed for another component userButton these two components UploadButton and UserButton are in main component.

Comment: Then you can define the `isDialogOpen ` state inside the main component(parent)  and pass that state as props to child ones. Inside a child, you can update the parent state using a callback prop to the parent.