# Refreshing Bootstrap4 Modal using React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks, modal-dialog, use-effect

I have a form inside a Bootstrap modal. In a form I have a **select** element and I want to feed **option** tags with state values. So I am using **useEffect** hook to update the state. The problem is if I toggle a modal, select options will be empty seems like it is using initial state before updating. Any help how can I update **option** tags after props and state changes. The following is a sample code snippet of how I am trying to implement this functionality:

**AddAnimals**

```js
export default function AddAnimals(props){
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    setAnimals(props.animals)
    console.log(animals)
  })
  
  return (
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-animal">Show modal</button>
    
    <div className="modal fade" id="add-animal">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-body">
            <form>
              <select className="form-control">
                {animals.map((animal)=><option value={animal}>{animal}</option>)}
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**console.log()** in that **useEffect** hook is initially logging an empty array and then an array with the data I want to use.

Comment: you should use a state management tool like redux. Or you should keep animals state in a parent component. If you have many state management scenarios like this, it is always better to go for a state management tool for react. There you can have a central state for the whole app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413565/react-hooks-how-to-pass-props-from-child-to-parent-component/62414218#62414218 this might help you, if you decide to maintain that state in it's parent component. This is a way to manage state between two child-parent components

Comment: Can you share stackblitz example for the same?